# Matrix report sorting logic

Tags: reporting, matrix

I have a matrix report with some grouping fields, and some other fields. I can set the 'order by' on grouping fields, but I cannot do this on the other non-grouping columns. I'm wondering if there is some logic behind this, or 'other' columns data is just ordered randomly?

In other words: Is the order of the data within groups deterministic?

```
row grouped |col grouped|other1|other2|
   A        |    Foo    |  32  | John |
            |    Bar    |   1  | Josh |
   B        |    Baz    |  23  | Anne |
            |    Boo    |   4  | Bart |
```